# How to stylize element in the top of the component's DOM tree?

Tags: css, angular, sass

I've a component whose selector is `app-menu-bar`. Its template:

```html
<nav>
</nav>
```

This style works:

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
    height: 64px;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #bbb;
}
```

But this doesn't work:

```css
app-menu-bar > nav {
    /* ... */
}
```

I'd like to do this to apply styles to only the root `nav`. Is this possible?

I could use Tailwind, but I guess I want to know it anyway.

---

Here's my `AppMenuBarComponent`:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu-bar',
  templateUrl: './menu-bar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu-bar.component.scss']
})
export class MenuBarComponent {

}
```

[image: Tag]

Comment: there is no selector `app-menu-bar` maybe you're missing a `.` or `#`?

Comment: @ITgoldman It's indeed `app-menu-bar` (a custom HTML element (tag) as specified by the Angular documentation).

Comment: ok my bad.  `>`  should refer to immediate children only

Comment: You can use `:host` to target the root. So `:host > nav` should do what you need. That said, why don't you use a css class? `<nav class="top-level-nav">` and `.top-level-nav { ... }`

Comment: @Martin I didn't know about `:host`, interesting... CSS classes may work, but they add verbosity to the template.